# Remove Unused Import 'keyboard shortcut' for Android Studio Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio

What shortcut we use on the keyboard to remove unused imports on mac,
 **on windows** its `Ctrl + alt + o`, I tried `cmd + option + o` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on a project > **Optimize imports**  will remove all unused imports.
**Keyboard shortcut**: `Ctrl` + `Option` + `o` should remove unused imports

[image: screen shot describing import]